# Relate data in a file

Tags: bash

I have a file with a huge data organized in columns, I want to extract the number of data in the first column $1, that have the same value in column $18.

Comment: Show a small sample of the file and desired output.

Comment: Do you want to use OCR on the columns of this image (no wonder the file is huge) and then extract data?

Comment: @jimmij 
I added a screenshot of the file in Windows, the R column is the $18, I need to get the number of data in $1 (A) column, that has the same value of $18.

In this example, 1106 has two records in column A (First column)

Comment: @Anthon  'No, I need to make it on Unix platform'

Comment: First export your data, get rid of the image, and show us what file format you are using (CSV, JSON, YAML, INI (yes with lists as values), XML). Get rid of the misleading and irrelevant image if it doesn't relate to the data **as it is, or will be** on your Unix platform.

Comment: @Anthon for the format it is **CSV**

Comment: @Azizieh7 please open this file is plain text editor, as `notebook` (on windows) or `emacs` (on unix), and then copy-paste few lines here. If this is proper csv file it should be possible. From the screenshot one cannot guess internal structure of the file.

Comment: Ordinary ASCII files with columns of data separated by `delimiter` ; on each row.

Comment: @Azizieh7 - hi and welcome to U&L. Can you please replace this screenshot with the actual ascii output from this file? Just a portion of it would be sufficient. You can use a command such as `head` to get just the first 10 lines of a text file. Then copy/paste it into your Q. It'll make it easier for others to assist you with your task.

Comment: @slm, Thank you for demonstrating things, however my problem solved by considering the $18 as a single array.
Thank you again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does "columns" mean here -- is this tab delimited?

Assuming that's the case:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1 == $18'
```

If you're using another delimiter, change the value passed to `-F`.

Comment: I have no idea what "same as Excel in Windows" even means -- Excel is a program, it doesn't have delimiters as part of its internal usage.

Answer (score 0):

You have empty fields and you don't specify if none of your fields have newlines. In general, but certainly when there is no confirmation that this is not a simple CSV file, you should use a proper CSV parsing library. E.g. the one from python:

```
import csv

fp = csv.reader(open('your_input.csv'))
for line in fp:
    if line[0] == line[17]:
        print(line[0])
```

Such libraries take care of most differences in CSV file formats automatically (e.g. because depending on your locale/language there might be semi-colons instead of commas) as well as dealing with multiline quoted fields