# How to change the first column of data in a file?

Tags: bash, files, awk, data

I have `.data` file containing a table of numbers with the column format:

```
m   x    y    z    vx    vy    vz
```

separated by tabs, with a depth of 2000. The file name is `initc.data`.

I want to change the value of the entire first column of the file.

I have tried using the following commands:

```
awk -F '$1 == 0.05' initc
```

and

```
awk -F '{print $1, "0.05"}' initc
```

to open the file and assign the first column the value `0.05`. These both open `awk` but don't run or produce output.

An example of the data in question is:

```
0.500000  0.500000  0.500000  0.500000  -1.500000  -1.500000  -1.500000
0.500000  0.567564  0.543674  0.536446  -1.500000  -1.500000  -1.500000
0.500000  0.454538  0.492286  0.501853  -1.500000  -1.500000  -1.500000
0.500000  0.574283  0.367439  0.668929  -1.500000  -1.500000  -1.500000
```

The closest related question I could find was this one: [*Related data in a file*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215892/relate-data-in-a-file).

Comment: You have `0.500000` in the first column and want to change all to `0.05`?

Comment: `awk '{$1="0.05"}1' initc.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` doesn't have the capability to make in-place substitution like the newer versions of `sed`. So, you need to direct output to a different file and get it back from this newly created file, as seen below:

```
awk '{$1="0.05"; print $0}' initc > initc.new && cat initc.new > initc
```

Answer (score 0):

interesting question - you could set a variable then use cut to parse the data and prepend the output with the content of your variable - via awk. (perhaps builtins exist to do this.. though the above will work).

```
x=$target
cat $file | cut -d" " -f2- | awk '{print info,$0 }' info=$target
```